# Change ListView Item selector programmatically

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a ListView which has 3 different types of items, and I want each of these categories to have a different selector. I've accomplished that so far using a different item layout for each category, but I think it's a bit silly, since the only thing that changes between those 3 layout files is the selector attribute `android:background="@drawable/cat1_selector"`

Isn't there a way to do this programmatically for each item via a method similar to `setSelector` in the `ListView` class ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or, you can set the selector of the View by Overriding the `getView()` method of your `ListAdapter`.
Check more [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html)

Comment: Thanks, it's what I did using the parent `ViewGroup.setBackground`method !